# binding long to user control property

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, controls

I seem to have run across an issue with binding and I have looked everywhere to try to resolve it.

I have a user control in ASP.NET that has a Channel ID public property which is a long.  I have added this user control to an empty ASPX page for testing.  When I simply add a number for this property value (i.e. `ChannelID="9"`) then it works perfectly.  When I try to do the following:

```
ChannelID="<%#: ChannelID %>"
```

where `ChannelID` is a variable on the hosting ASPX page, it tells me it cannot convert from string to long as a compilation error.

What I have gathered so far through my research is that the data binding functions convert values to strings rather than retaining their original data types.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have multiple user controls in a single page that all bind a property through a shared interface to the same value of the host page.  I know that I could do this in code behind but that is what I am trying to avoid.  I also know that I could simply change the data type to string and then convert it before it is sent from the user control to the database....that will be the route I go if I cannot find another solution.

There is not really code I can post because the scenario is extremely basic.But here is the declaration of the user code on the host page:

```
<UC:ChanControl ID="ChanControl1" runat="server" IsActiveView="true"
    DisplayMode="Normal" ChannelID="<%#: ChannelID%>" />
```

Again, the `ChannelID` property in the host page and the user control are both set to long.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this  `ChannelID='<%#: Eval(ChannelID) %>'`
or

```
ChannelID='<%#: Eval(ChannelID).ToString() %>'
```

Comment: you can also use ChannelID='<%#: Bind(ChannelID) %>'